# CSS a:active pseudo class not Working

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked here before and I've done some googling to see if i could get it to work but the solutions I find don't at all work for me.
Here's my code

```
<div id="rightbar" class="float-r">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td colspan="2"><a class="block active" href="dashboard.php">My Dashboard</a></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr>
            <td><a class="block" href="profile.php">My Profile</a></td>             
        </tr>           
        <tr>
            <td><a class="block" href="edit_profile.php">Edit Personal Details Form</a></td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="block" href="edit_form.php">Edit Members Form</a></td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="last-child"><a style="border-bottom:solid 1px #eaeaea;width:235px;" class="block" href="logout.php">Log Out</a></td>             
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div>

.float-r {
 float: right;
}

#rightbar {
background: #ffffff;
float: right;
width: 250px;
margin-top: 10px;
height: 530px;
margin-right: 10px; 
border-bottom: solid 1px #c8c9c9;
}

#rightbar a {
width:235px;
color: #000;
font-size:14px;
text-decoration:none;
}

#rightbar a:hover{
background-color:#efefef;
width:235px;
}

#rightbar a:active{
background-color:#eaeaea;
width:235px;
}
```

I want when I click a link and hover out of it the background on the a:active should change take for Instance Stackoverflow here if you scroll to the top you would see options like Questions,Tags,Users,Badges if i click on each of those links the background changes to Orange. I want something like that. Thanks.

Comment: What are you toggling the active with?

Comment: Everything seems to work. What do you suppose not to work as intended?

Comment: Did you try #rightbar table tbody tr td a:hover{
background-color:#efefef;
width:235px;
}

Comment: @AdvaitS yeap still didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working fine. You can see here when i switch it to red, when you hold the mouse click down it works correctly.

https://jsfiddle.net/zk3sw43m/2/

only changed the red here for clarity

```
 #rightbar a:active{
background-color:red;
width:235px;
}
```

Comment: see what I mean is when i click the link and hover out i want it to still remain red, take for Instance Stackoverflow here if you scroll to the top you would see options like Questions,Tags,Users,Badges if i click on each of those links the background changes to Orange. I want something like that

Comment: @Rhyno_xD that is a whole different functionality than the css :active. You may want to try something like swapping a class onto the item and changing the css. For example the stack overflow uses the class "youarehere" to style like you are saying there. CSS :active is just when you are in the state of clicking the item. See here for reference - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Comment: i see what you mean, it work now, but I'm using php include to add the headers to pages that will be a little problem doing it but I'll think of something. Thanks Alot.

Answer (score 0):

You chosen very close colors: [#efefef](http://www.color-hex.com/color/efefef) and [#eaeaea](http://www.color-hex.com/color/eaeaea), that's why difference is hard to see.